# How to connect multiple docker container services with 1433 on host machine

Tags: docker, minikube

I have 4 services in docker containes and they are running on munikube infrastructure.
All 4 services are connected to same database server accessing same database which is hosted on Host machine...

Now i need all 4 services to connect with host machine SQL database...

At a time only one service is able to connect with database and others could not...
Firewall is OFF in my host machine...

Tried exposing 1433 port on container and also tried tunneling 1433 with host like -p 1433:1433 but could not succeed yet..

Any thought on this ???

Comment: I have removed the <sql> tag since this isn't related to the SQL _language_. Instead you can add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to work with some custom docker networking components:
https://docs.docker.com/network/

These are usually done under the hood when Docker-compose is used for example.